# Cannot modify the file "projectname.dll"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, web-publishing, publishing-site

When I'm publishing the site, it gives me error. It says that cannot modify ProjectName.dll. [Error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK8or.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's usually because the DLL is currently in use, either via IIS Express or running directly from the console. Shutdown IIS Express, close any open console windows, etc., and then try again.